# Why does this code require me to click twice for the calendar to show up?

Tags: jquery

I am posting this question after getting really desperate trying to solve it. 
I have to click the link twice before the calendar will show up.

Does anyone have an idea of what I have coded incorrectly.? Thanks for any
suggestions.

calendar.php has the following in its document.ready function:

```
---------------calendar.php------------------
    <script type='text/javascript'>

        $(document).ready(function() {

            $('#calendar').fullCalendar({
                header: {
                    left: 'prev,next today',
                    center: 'title',
                    right: 'month,agendaWeek,agendaDay'
                }

            });

        });

    </script>
```

And the below is the css in calendar.php:

```
    <style type='text/css'>
        #calendar {
            width: 950px;
            margin: 0 auto;
            }
    </style>

---------------------------------------------
```

Here is the code in menu.js that uses AJAX load function to load the calendar into content Div:

```
-------------menu.js------------------
$(document).ready(function(){
        sections.click(function(){

        switch(this.id){
        case "classes":
            content.load("classcal.php", function(responseText){
                loadjscssfile('../fullcalendar/fullcalendar.css', "css");
                loadjscssfile('jquery-1.6.1',"js"); 
                loadjscssfile('../jquery/jquery-ui-1.8.11.custom.min.js',"js");
                loadjscssfile('../fullcalendar/fullcalendar.min.js',"js");
            });
            break;
        ...
        ...
        }//switch

        });
});
-----------------------------------------------
```